# Решение минимизации рециклических зависимостей

Tags: алгоритм

Всем, привет.
Есть список объектов, которые имеют проперти, которые могут быть получены в ходе работы других объектов, объекты рассчитываются по очереди и основная проблема заключается в том, что проперти, одного объекта рассчитывается по очереди после этого объекта[image: Пример связи объектов]

Необходимо чтобы obj2 был рассчитан до obj1

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если это вопрос о графах, то топологическая сортировка вам в помощь. Если не о графах, то непонятно, что вам надо сделать.

Comment: Если это ООП, то там это само всё сделается, если правильно объекты описать. Пока всё слишком абстрактно.